# Xcode The archive contains nothing that can be signed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

After I archive my project and try to validate or submit to the app store I get the error: "The archive contains nothing that can be signed. Verify that your build process has compiled binaries and copied in bundled resources."

How do I fix this?

Comment: please add more detail to get a more specific answer

Comment: I duplicated you question as I had the same issue for days, but I wanted to add more detail. A few minutes ago I manage to find my problem. I realise your question was asked almost two years ago, but could you say if this was maybe your problem too? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45099253/5152481

Comment: Do not downrate this question. I've had this issue for months and there really is nothing more to it. Xcode simply won't export the archive.

Answer (score 1):

I will elaborate springrapher answer as this answer helped me:

In your Target -> Build Settings search for:

1. VALID_ARCHS and make sure arm64 is included
2. search for Excluded Architectures and make sure arm64 is NOT mentioned there

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Build Settings for the project to make sure you include arm64 in your supported architectures