# Archive Export error: The archive contains nothing that can be signed

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

My app runs on devices and simulators. The app archives with no errors. When I try to export I get the following error:

[image: export error message]

The log file `IDEDistribution.critical.log` contains the following:

> 2017-07-07 07:40:03 +0000 [MT] Failed to generate distribution items with error: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=12 "The archive contains nothing that can be signed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The archive contains nothing that can be signed., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Verify that your build process has compiled binaries and copied in bundled resources.}
>   2017-07-07 07:40:03 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=12 "The archive contains nothing that can be signed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The archive contains nothing that can be signed., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Verify that your build process has compiled binaries and copied in bundled resources.}

The contents of the `.xcarchive`:
[image: archive content]

The `.app` also contains all the usual stuff.

I am sure there may be more information needed. Please ask and I will provide what I can.

Comment: Same questions as https://stackoverflow.com/a/37614557/5152481, but that answer does not work for me.

Comment: This answer also does not fix my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/33047767/5152481

Comment: I may be able to get to the problem soon. Fastlane exports without a problem while Xcode still can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the archive destination directory to a location on the local SSD (and not an external HDD).

I have not had this problem again after I did this and I recall having started running into the problem after I started trying to free up space on my mac.

Answer (score 7):

What fixed my issue was including `arm64` in the app architecture,

In your Target -> Build Settings search for:

1. VALID_ARCHS and make sure `arm64` is included.
2. search for Excluded Architectures and make sure `arm64` is NOT mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

At last! There may have been other issues too, but only after I changed the scheme container was I able to export. And I knew it had something to do with CocoaPods.

Before `pod install` your scheme may look something like this:

[image]

There are no other container options.

After `pod install` it will look like this:

[image]

Once I selected the `Workspace` container I started seeing a difference in the build and consequently the export worked.

Comment: Its breaking again. So now I know the problem is intermittent.

Answer (score 0):

For me helped relaunching an Xcode. I think the problem is because all archives stored in a separate HDD and it was something with the access to it by Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error when I was resolving error occurred after shifting from Intel based mac to M1 based mac for a ReactNative based project. For resolving some fixes, I had to exclude the `arm64` in the project build settings, but I also excluded it in the target. I removed the "arm64" from all schemes of the excluded targets of Excluded Architectures of the project target and rebuilt the code. It worked.