# All framework error when launch framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, plist, simulator

I have a project on react native,

I'm Stack all day with this error I try a lot of things but nothing works, build successfully but the application is not launched on device or simulator here is the error I got

> Could not install at this time.
> Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/BT/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/32A76497-8C7B-4639-B3F9-80379AF5CB9A/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.SEVqpI/extracted/XXXXXX.app/Frameworks/RCTVibration.framework; Extra info about Info.plist: Couldn't stat /Users/BT/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/32A76497-8C7B-4639-B3F9-80379AF5CB9A/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.SEVqpI/extracted/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/RCTVibration.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory

Even I reset to the old version of the project witch worked perfectly I'm getting the error

When I add a info.plist to RCTVibration other library has the same problem as 20 library

I tried to clean project, close xcode, delete derived data, restart Mac i tried Embded Framework copy only when installing ... but still stuck i can't delete use_frameworks! because i have dynamic and no dynamic framework

On device i'm getting a different error :

Details

### Unable to install "XXXXX"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103

### Could not inspect the application package.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
User Info: {
DVTRadarComponentKey = 282703;
MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000051)";
"com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000129dbe93f DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000129dfd124 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d9a1b43 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000129dfce65 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000129c6dd28 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 3513
5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010dad02aa **DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK** + 7
6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010dad1ecc __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6d0416c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6d042658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6d047c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6d0485d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6d051c09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6d29ca3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6d29bb77 start_wqthread + 15
);
}

System Information

macOS Version 10.15.7 (Build 19H2)
Xcode 12.0.1 (17220)

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Any solution for that issue?

Comment: I already publish a solution worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried even uninstall xcode and install again another version, also pull project git on a new location, create new simulator, restart device nothing worked

What worked for is adding for every framework, click on choose info.plist file like image show it and pods-Project-info.plist and it will be filled with correct information
It's not the best solution because it takes me a lot of time to associate all plist file, but it's the only solution that worked for me

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, after trying many things and wasting a lot of time.

Comment: unbelievable... It cost me almost 2 days to make this work. I was going to resign from project.. And it went corrupted suddenly... unbelievable.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Do not embed Frameworks in xcode]

I was getting a similar error even after the builds passed and the simulator popped up. But the app was prevented from opening as it seems there was some .plist file missing in the frameworks.
I rechecked and set the Embed mode to **"Do not Embed"** for each of the frameworks added in the .xcworkspace target > General.

I also might had Clean the build folder (Cmd + Shift + K), closed the xcode, deleted DerivedData, `pod deintegrate && pod update` before shooting the Run in xcode again.

Other Info: Xcode-13.2.1, React Native project, M1Pro mac, Xcode running in Rosetta, Excluded Architecture - arch64 (in <s>[target &](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71329671/5794873)</s> project Build Settings)

Answer (score 1):

Try running your project with npx react-native run-ios.
After hours of struggling and trying everything I found (cleaning derived data, erasing content and settings of simulators, reinstalling Xcode...)
This is the only thing that made it work, I was even able to build with Xcode after running the build with npx.

Answer (score 0):

Clean drive data in XCODE preferences, clean and then rebuild the project. Hope it works!

Comment: drive data ? you mean deriveddata ? i already try that ;(

Comment: Run this in terminal:  open $TMPDIR/TemporaryItems and delete all temporary files. Try it! It's all hit and trial.

Comment: Thanks for the tip i try that but nothing changed :(

Answer (score 0):

One probable solution is following the steps:

1. Run pod install command in your terminal
2. Before installing App again delete content of your Derived Data
   folder

Build and run to install the app.

Moreover if the above 2 steps doesn't work the try removing use_frameworks! from your Podfile and follow steps 1 & 2.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried all the methods mentioned above, but they didn't work, and when I debugged all the Cocoapod and XcodeProj in Ruby, it was confirmed that the problem occurred due to the special setting. It may be a unique case, but it is very simple to check, so I recommend you to try it...

if `ENV['INFOPLIST_FILE']` has a file for any `Info.plist`,
CocoaPods doesn't make Info.plist for Pod targets.
reference: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/blob/29cd0821d47f864abbd1ca80f23ff2aded0adfed/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/build_configuration.rb#L115

I put this phrase in for the test and I was able to confirm that the file existed.
`puts "#{ENV['INFOPLIST_FILE']}"`

Finally, I could solved adding this line on top of `Podfile`.
`ENV['INFOPLIST_FILE'] = nil`

By the way, I don't know how I ended up assigning a specific Info.plist file to ENV...