# Project reactnative error launch iOS Could not inspect the application package

Tags: ios, react-native, ipad, device

Certificate is ok, i'm not having latin characters, i didn't add any new ressources or folder, it has been working for days and today it's stopped i'm getting this error before installing on ipad:

```
Unable to install "myApplication"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
--
Could not inspect the application package.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 282703;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000051)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000128f893b8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000128fc7ae1 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010f5d1b7c DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000128fc7822 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000128e38999 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.294 + 3534
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010f704931 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010f70655b __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20506603 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff205077e6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2050d5ca _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2050e08d _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20517bed _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 811
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff206ae4c0 _pthread_wqthread + 314
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff206ad493 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.3.1 (Build 20E241)
Xcode 12.5 (18205) (Build 12E262)
Timestamp: 2021-09-29T18:22:35+02:00
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: This solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977628/all-framework-error-when-launch-framework-info-plist-no-such-file-or-directory