# Issue trying to run app on iOS simulator missing a plist from Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

```
Simulator device failed to install the application. Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code: 1 Failure Reason: Please try again later. Recovery Suggestion: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/mbp16/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8D067001-51D4-4A49-8F37-B565387E3A4F/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.1ezCsM/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework; Extra info about "/Users/mbp16/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8D067001-51D4-4A49-8F37-B565387E3A4F/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.1ezCsM/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/mbp16/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8D067001-51D4-4A49-8F37-B565387E3A4F/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.1ezCsM/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-01-26 20:06:18 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    SimCallingSelector = "installApplication:withOptions:error:"; }
-- Simulator device failed to install the application. Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code: 1 Failure Reason: Please try again later. Recovery Suggestion: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/mbp16/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8D067001-51D4-4A49-8F37-B565387E3A4F/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.1ezCsM/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework; Extra info about "/Users/mbp16/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8D067001-51D4-4A49-8F37-B565387E3A4F/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.1ezCsM/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/mbp16/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8D067001-51D4-4A49-8F37-B565387E3A4F/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.1ezCsM/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory User Info: {
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    SimCallingSelector = "installApplication:withOptions:error:"; }
-- Unable to Install “MyApp ” Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code: 1 Failure Reason: Please try again later. Recovery Suggestion: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/mbp16/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8D067001-51D4-4A49-8F37-B565387E3A4F/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.1ezCsM/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework; Extra info about "/Users/mbp16/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8D067001-51D4-4A49-8F37-B565387E3A4F/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.1ezCsM/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/mbp16/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8D067001-51D4-4A49-8F37-B565387E3A4F/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.1ezCsM/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
-- Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/mbp16/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8D067001-51D4-4A49-8F37-B565387E3A4F/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.1ezCsM/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework; Extra info about "/Users/mbp16/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8D067001-51D4-4A49-8F37-B565387E3A4F/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.1ezCsM/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/mbp16/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8D067001-51D4-4A49-8F37-B565387E3A4F/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.1ezCsM/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain Code: 35 User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[MIBundle _validateWithError:]";
    LegacyErrorString = PackageInspectionFailed;
    SourceFileLine = 64; }
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone16,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "17.4 (21E5184i)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "355.18";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.100.52";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = "x86_64";
    "operation_duration_ms" = 22939;
    "operation_errorCode" = 1;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IXUserPresentableErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator17.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.4";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator; }
```

System Information

macOS Version 14.3 (Build 23D56) Xcode 15.3 (22617) (Build 15E5178i) Timestamp: 2024-01-26T20:06:18Z

The above outputs in the error message when trying to install my app on simulator. I am hopeful that someone here can recommend a fix. I have exhausted google and can't find any solutions so hope the SO community knows the issue.

Comment: Seeing the same, if you create a Github issue for it, I'll +1 it.

Comment: @TristanWarner-Smith appreciated but I don’t use GitHub. I can’t figure out how to use it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

March 9, 2024 edit: **Update to the fixed 10.22 **.

---

If you're using Firebase 10.20.0, does it help to **revert to Firebase 10.19.0**?

Based on the release notes, `Info.plist` files were removed in 10.20.0.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_10200_-_january_16_2023

Another third possibility, in addition to Rainy sidewalks and ncooke3's suggestions in the other answer, is that this is an Xcode 15.3 specific issue since it hasn't been seen on earlier Xcode versions. **Does it make a difference to use an Xcode 15.2 or earlier?**

Comment: worked fine on xcode 15.2. issue started in 15.3. However going back to 15.2 the issue still persists.

Comment: This worked. TY. uninstalled the package and reinstalled setting version to maximum 10.19.0

Comment: FYI, `10.22.0` still has an issue with the `GoogleAppMeasurementOnDeviceConversion.framework`, but `10.22.1` should finally fix everything. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/12441#issuecomment-1984133203

Comment: Good point - updating.

Comment: Well, `10.22.1` still doesn't work either. Such a waste of time. Couldn't FB team test it well on latest Xcode 15.3?

Comment: 10.22.1 has a known issue with Analytics frameworks for macOS and Catalyst that will be fixed in 10.23.0. If you have another issue, please report at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues

Comment: This is worked for me, i got this issue after i updated the Xcode to 15.3

Answer (score 1):

i think main issue is mismatch of Info.plist file for the FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework .

so please try the following tweaks and see if works .

1st as useful in most of the cases -> **Close Xcode and the simulator, then reopen them and try installing the app again.**
(i am assuming you have done and try the above obvious approach so then try the following )

2nd. make sure xCode is updated to latest version.

3.Clean the build folder for that -  Product -> Clean Build Folder in Xcode.

4. delete derived data for that - Go to Xcode Preferences then -> Locations and click on the small arrow next to the Derived Data path then the derived data folder in Finder will open then Delete the folder corresponding to your project.

5.check  that the FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework is included in your project also the path is correctly specified.

6. try with reinstall Firebase Firestore -  remove the firestore framework from your project and then add it back again make sure to follow the official installation [steps provided by Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).

Comment: Thank you.tried all those steps and still persists as an issue.

Comment: what version are you using,?  it is imported as paul  highlighted the issu with version 10.20.0  and further

Comment: I would also recommend [wiping the simulator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-a-simulator-for-your-environment#Restart-or-reset-a-simulated-device) by selecting `Device > Erase All Contents and Settings` in the Simulator.app's menu bar.

Comment: @ncooke3 I deleted and reinstalled all simulators. No joy

Comment: can you look at this answer [All framework error when launch framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64979956) . it is not limited to just the FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework issue .

Comment: @Rainysidewalks I do not get those options to select plist. Possible cos I installed via swift package manager not cocoa pods.

Comment: let me see further . will let you know if got any?