# App installation failed: Unable to Install “MyApp"

Tags: ios, xcode, google-cloud-firestore

I just updated my Xcode to Version 15.3 (15E204a) and it also updated to iOS 17.4. I cleaned my build folder, restarted Xcode and my computer. I still keep getting this error when I want to run my app on the simulator. I also have Firebase integrated with this app.

> Please try again later. Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/Name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B987B095-EA99-4A3D-BDBD-B2A046CDC4E2/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.x4iOVw/extracted/BiteCount.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework; Extra info about "/Users/Name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B987B095-EA99-4A3D-BDBD-B2A046CDC4E2/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.x4iOVw/extracted/BiteCount.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/Name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B987B095-EA99-4A3D-BDBD-B2A046CDC4E2/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.x4iOVw/extracted/BiteCount.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory

Could anyone please help me solve this, so I can run my app again within the simulator? I had no issues before the update and I currently have no major errors within the code itself.

I cleaned my build folder, restarted Xcode and my computer, reset the simulator iPhone and I am running the app on the iPhone 15 Pro Max iOS 17.4

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77888962/issue-trying-to-run-app-on-ios-simulator-missing-a-plist-from-firebase

Comment: I think I am facing a similar issue with Xcode 15.3 and iOS 17.4.

The issue concerns another framework and another file but the message is the same and only concerns build on simulator or real device done on 15.3 and iOS 17.4. 

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/748660

I think that for some reasons Xcode 15.3 drops some random files while packing for iOS 17.4...