# Xcode archive error : The archive contains nothing that can be signed

Tags: ios, xcode

While trying to upload to testflight I get the following issues. Tried various solutions from google like  [Archive Export error: The archive contains nothing that can be signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44966406/archive-export-error-the-archive-contains-nothing-that-can-be-signed)
but din't get it to work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you build for archive successfully ? Did you Archive ? Do you export from the organiser ?